# Android nice display of tabular data

Tags: android

I'd like to display a table in an android UI, with dynamic information.
This table has a constant number of rows an columns.
The format of each cell is also constant and is for instance a textview.
The content of the cells is dynamic.

Though, The text in the cells may be more or less long, so that it is displayed on one line or several lines, that is my issue.
I would like to display my table nicely so that all the rows have the same height, of course basing on the height of the 'highest' cell of the table, and so that the whole table is displayed on the screen.

It seems to me after being stuck in my search, that Android has not been designed to do that, and maybe the way I want to display my data is 'old fashioned'.

So I'd like to ask to you, experts, 2 questions:

1. Is there a workaround to harmonize row height in a table?
2. Is there a better practice to display nicely my data?

Comment: You can set a fixed row height. If you google, you'll also find at least one table component.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am sorry, I have forgotten to precise that the content of my cells is dynamic. So I don't know how to define the row height to set.

Answer (score 0):

TableLayout

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

you can create a TableRow and then add Views to it to create columns entries.

```
 TableRow row = new TableRow ( context );

 row.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ,
                                                 TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );


 row.addView( <some column view >);

 table.addView( row );

  etc etc...
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have forgotten to precise that the content of my cells is dynamic. Your proposition won't do the job I think.

Comment: You could do that with this if you extend the TableLayout class. Alternatively, you could use a ListView and an adapter to achieve a table like look.

Comment: Extend the TableLayout class sounds good, the other solution as well, though I cannot figure out how to get the max row height, and apply it to all the rows.